# Why is .first() in jquery targeting the second element?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm writing a basic carousel/slider that's supposed to scroll infinitely. Basically I'm trying to shift the container over the width of the slide, move the first slide to to the end, then move the container back.

For some reason .first() is moving the second element not the first:

```
$('.half-slider .next').click(function(){
    var slideW = $(this).parent().parent().find('.slide').first().outerWidth();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.slides').animate({'margin-left': -slideW},function(){
        var firstSlide = $(this).find('.slide').first();
        var lastSlide = $(this).find('.slide').last();
        firstSlide.after(lastSlide);
    });
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLAaF/2/

*just select "next" in the fiddle. "prev" isn't active in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstSlide.after(lastSlide);
```

This will put the `lastSlide` after the `firstSlide`.  Based on your statement that you "move the first slide to the end", I think you meant:

```
firstSlide.insertAfter(lastSlide);
```

To put the first slide after the last slide.

Comment: I made this change in the jsfiddle and it works after the first interaction. The first click goes from 1 straight to 3 but after that it goes in the correct order as though it's moving 1 and 2 to the end not just 1.